# GET http://localhost:3000/api/jobdetail 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ionic-framework, mean-stack

In my database(MongoDB) I have 2 collections called users and jobdetail.I'm trying to connect to second collection jobdetail & retrieve the data. This is my app.js code.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');
// Connect To Database
mongoose.connect(config.database);
// On Connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to database '+config.database);
});

// On Error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Database error: '+err);
});

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const users = require('./routes/users');



// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.send('Invalid endpoint');
});

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
  });

// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use('/users', users);

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log("Server started on port:", port); 
});
```

This is my routes file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('../config/database');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');

// Register
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    //code
      });

      User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
          res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
        } else {
          res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
        }
      });
});

// Update User
router.post('/update', function(req, res, next) {
  //code

})


// Authenticate
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch){
        const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
          expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
        });

        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: 'JWT '+token,
          user: {
            id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong password'});
      }
    });
  });
});

//get job details 
router.get('/jobdetail', function(req,res) {
  console.log('fetching jobs');
  jobDetails.find(function(err,jobs) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(jobs);
    }
  });
});






// Profile
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({user: req.user});
  });



module.exports = router;
```

This is provider.ts file

```
getJobDetails() {
    if(this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
      this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/jobdetail')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
    });
  }
```

I'm getting the error like

> polyfills.js:3 GET http://localhost:3000/api/jobdetail 404 (Not Found)
>   s @ polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 onScheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.js:3 (anonymous) @
>   polyfills.js:3 o.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.js:2 (anonymous) @
>   http.js:1640 Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
>   Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160 MapOperator.call @ map.js:56
>   Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157 (anonymous) @ jobs-data.ts:23
>   t @ polyfills.js:3 webpackJsonp.181.JobsDataProvider.getJobDetails @
>   jobs-data.ts:20 webpackJsonp.260.FeedsPage.ionViewDidLoad @
>   feeds.ts:63 ViewController._lifecycle @ view-controller.js:486
>   ViewController._didLoad @ view-controller.js:369
>   NavControllerBase._didLoad @ nav-controller-base.js:768 t.invoke @
>   polyfills.js:3 onInvoke @ core.js:4749 t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3 r.run
>   @ polyfills.js:3 NgZone.run @ core.js:4566
>   NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM @ nav-controller-base.js:463
>   NavControllerBase._transition @ nav-controller-base.js:540 (anonymous)
>   @ nav-controller-base.js:261 t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3 onInvoke @
>   core.js:4749 t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3 r.run @ polyfills.js:3
>   (anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3 t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
>   onInvokeTask @ core.js:4740 t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3 r.runTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 o @ polyfills.js:3 Promise.then (async) r @
>   polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 onScheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.js:3 f @ polyfills.js:3
>   c @ polyfills.js:3 (anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3 webpackJsonpCallback @
>   bootstrap ac2fad340272940ddf57:21 (anonymous) @ 0.js:1 core.js:1448
>   ERROR Response {_body: "↵↵↵Cannot GET /api/jobdetail↵↵↵", status: 404,
>   ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}headers:
>   Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)}ok: falsestatus:
>   404statusText: "Not Found"type: 2url:
>   "http://localhost:3000/api/jobdetail"_body: "↵↵↵↵Error↵↵↵
>
> ```
> Cannot GET
> /api/jobdetail
> ```
>
> ↵↵↵"**proto**: Body
>   defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1448 ErrorHandler.handleError @
>   core.js:1509 IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:61
>   next @ core.js:5497 schedulerFn @ core.js:4331
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:239 SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:186 Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:126 Subscriber.next
>   @ Subscriber.js:90 Subject.next @ Subject.js:55 EventEmitter.emit @
>   core.js:4311 (anonymous) @ core.js:4771 t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
>   r.run @ polyfills.js:3 NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4697
>   onHandleError @ core.js:4771 t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3 r.runTask
>   @ polyfills.js:3 e.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3 p @ polyfills.js:2 v @
>   polyfills.js:2 error (async) O @ polyfills.js:2 t.scheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 onScheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleEventTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 (anonymous) @ polyfills.js:2 (anonymous) @ http.js:1639
>   Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172 Observable.subscribe @
>   Observable.js:160 MapOperator.call @ map.js:56 Observable.subscribe @
>   Observable.js:157 (anonymous) @ jobs-data.ts:23 t @ polyfills.js:3
>   webpackJsonp.181.JobsDataProvider.getJobDetails @ jobs-data.ts:20
>   webpackJsonp.260.FeedsPage.ionViewDidLoad @ feeds.ts:63
>   ViewController._lifecycle @ view-controller.js:486
>   ViewController._didLoad @ view-controller.js:369
>   NavControllerBase._didLoad @ nav-controller-base.js:768 t.invoke @
>   polyfills.js:3 onInvoke @ core.js:4749 t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3 r.run
>   @ polyfills.js:3 NgZone.run @ core.js:4566
>   NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM @ nav-controller-base.js:463
>   NavControllerBase._transition @ nav-controller-base.js:540 (anonymous)
>   @ nav-controller-base.js:261 t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3 onInvoke @
>   core.js:4749 t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3 r.run @ polyfills.js:3
>   (anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3 t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
>   onInvokeTask @ core.js:4740 t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3 r.runTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 o @ polyfills.js:3 Promise.then (async) r @
>   polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 onScheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.js:3 f @ polyfills.js:3
>   c @ polyfills.js:3 (anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3 webpackJsonpCallback @
>   bootstrap ac2fad340272940ddf57:21 (anonymous) @ 0.js:1

I've also tried it using postman it displaying the error as

> Error
>
> ```
> Cannot GET /api/jobdetail
> ```

Comment: Hello, the error message seems pretty straight forward, what exactly is your question?

Comment: why I'm unable to get the response

Answer (score 1):

I think your valid endpoint is:
*http://localhost:3000/users/jobdetail*

**NOT**

*http://localhost:3000/api/jobdetail*

Answer (score 0):

Change like this, i think your find job details without condition:

```
jobDetails.find({}, (err,jobs) => {
if(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
else {
  res.json(jobs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is pretty un-mysterious. You are exposing the route:

```
/jobdetail
```

not:

```
/api/jobdetail
```

The 404 error tells you this.

Comment: Write a test route, make sure it works. Your server is definitely not exposing that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a variable named `jobDetails` in the routes file but that variable isn't declared anywhere. Either that's the problem, or you didn't post all of your code.

Here's the offending route, notice the 4th line down:

```
//get job details 
router.get('/jobdetail', function(req,res) {
  console.log('fetching jobs');
  jobDetails.find(function(err,jobs) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(jobs);
    }
  });
});
```